# Do I need to encode/decode query parameters between an ajax request and the php receiving that request?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I want to send whole sql command through ajax call as a argument. Do I have to do escape it or to do something special about that?

Something like `tools.php?database=db2&sql=select * from table`

If escaping is necessary

- how do I do it in javascript/jquery
- what do I do then in php to read it

## NOTE - very specific use-case & system settings

The web server is accessible **only from inside** our internal network. If anybody breaks in they can get all the databases so my 'little application' with I am improving via this question is not important at all. I have already implemented DROPping of whole database, updating whole columns, updating db's settings etc via my web application. I just want to add this new feature. I might even happen that I am going to be the only use of this web application.

Comment: Please don't. This is totally dangerous. Really, and obvious. `tools.php?database=db2&sql=drop table customers`

Comment: Totally agree with @Albin. Please predefine the commands you want to have executed and call those. God kills a kitten every time you do stuff like this :p

Comment: Could be an sql frontend where you _want_ to allow this kind of statement.

Comment: @Albin: for argument sake, what if the DB Role have only retrieval permission?

Comment: @Volk, if that was the case, do you really think they'd be asking if a query needs to be encoded?

Comment: @Josh Smeaton : Obviously yes ;-)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might want to consider using `POST` requests instead of `GET` requests, to avoid HTTP caching...

Comment: @Radek, even if the server is only accessible inside your network, what's there to stop a bad guy from posting an innocent-looking hyperlink to `http://10.20.30.40/tools.php?sql=drop+table+*` to some web forum _outside_ your firewall that someone _inside_ your firewall reads?

Comment: @Henning: Nothing stops him :-) But to do some 'harm' to us somebody from the company would have to `find` the link, `click` the link, `ip` must be right one, `php file` name must the right one, `structure of url` arguments must be correct, `database name` must be right one .... and then in most cases I would 'only' restore another backup ....

Comment: @Josh: There is no need to be patronising. "If you could set relevant permissions on your MySQL database then you wouldn't be asking a question here about AJAX escaping." It's just nonsense. You're calling the OP stupid at every turn with no basis for it.

Comment: @Tom, perhaps it wasn't a very nice assumption, but I still believe it was a fair assumption; even if/though I was wrong. At "every turn" is a bit of a stretch though, it was a single comment, and was rebuffed right away by the person I commented on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**PEOPLE, DON'T USE THIS CODE IF YOU ARE NOT ABSOLUTELY SURE WHAT YOU ARE DOING**

This code is subject to catastrophical security breaches, so don't use it unless you absolutely sure that **no evil people** will access it.

Sending:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: *your backend url here*,
    data: {database: 'db', sql: "select * from table"},
    success: function(data, textStatus){
        //perform any processing with data returned from backend here
    }
});
```

Receiving:

```
<?php
    $sql = $_POST['sql'];
    $db = $_POST['db'];
    //db connection
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    //processing query result, $rslt is processing result
    echo json_encode($rslt);
?>
```

Hovewer, it's not a good idea to send SQL from client, such an approach is extremely vulnerable to SQL-injections. But, if you are sure you want to shoot yourself in a leg...

Comment: This goes beyond SQL injection. More like, *entire query injection*

Comment: I'm surprised to have 4 upvotes on this answer... People, it's really, **really** bad practice, don't use it.

Comment: @J0HN: Can I use `type: 'get'`? I am already using get in my existing ajax/php code.

Comment: Sure you can, but than you'll have to change `$_POST` to `$_GET`. Also, you may use `jQuery.get`. It is a shorthand function, so I prefer using `jQuery.ajax`, but they both will work.

Comment: @JOHN why would you even post this? The OP *clearly* does not understand the security implications of this.

Comment: Maybe because he wants to help?

Comment: @Stephen, it is up to him to decide. I've warned him a lot, even more than you. So, don't play "elder brother", allow Radek to be responsible for what he is doing.

Comment: This is not about "playing elder brother". The OP asked for advice. The level of complexity of the question, indicates the OP is not overly experienced, and thus does not truly understand the associated dangers with this approach.

Saying "hey by the way this is a really dangerous idea, but hey here is the code to do it anyway" is irresponsible, IMO.

Anyone who truly understands the implications of doing something like this, will not be asking such a basic question.

Comment: @Stephen, what's the aim of this discussion? Just FYI, I've upvoted your answer and first commend to the question itself, so I share your point of view. So what do you want from me? My point of view on that question is that people and especially programmers have to be responsible for their actions. So, if the OP asks for something - I answer. If it's dangerous - I warn and discourage him a lot, but to use this approach or not, it's his responsibility. So unless you are going to change my mind on this, this discussion is useless.

Comment: @JOHN exactly - this is about being responsible. A driving instructor doesn't say to a student "OK now you can drive a two times the legal limit like so, but it's really dangerous so you shouldn't do it!".

If you agree that what the OP wanted to do is dangerous, why not simply state that, and advise the OP to use another method - why post a solution that you believe is dangerous.

You are clearly more experienced than the OP. By giving advice, you have to accept some responsibility as well, because despite saying "this is dangerous", you still provided the example.

Comment: sometimes driving instructors do that, it helps in emergency situations.

Comment: @Stephen, let's discuss it [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102536/dangerous-answers) Btw, speed limit is a really bad example, because some kind of people *has* to drive like that. You know, ambulance drivers, firefighters, police, other emergency services...

Comment: "A driving instructor doesn't say to a student "OK now you can drive a two times the legal limit like so, but it's really dangerous so you shouldn't do it!"."  --- No, he teaches you how to use the accelerator pedal, teaching you how to do the unsafe thing, and trusts that you don't abuse the power.

Comment: This is a Q&A website. There was a Q, and this is the A. To complete the "helpfulness" aspect, it's very clear about the issues with this scenario. +1 from me, and there is no issue here. // Naysayers: if it helps you, think of this as a remote command-line database management tool. Does a client like SQLYog or PhpMyAdmin prevent you from writing arbitrary queries? _No it does not._ Shush and move along!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - and if you actually read my posted answer, you'll see that I said, "If you're building a system that is an exception to this rule, you wouldn't be asking this question" - IMO the OP is not experienced enough to create an SQL client.

Comment: @Stephen: Yea, I read it. I find it slightly offensive. What does AJAX escaping have to do with SQL permissions? How can you gauge his skills with one based on having posted a question about the other? You're basically calling the OP stupid with no basis at all, and thus refusing to answer the stated question. You might as well not have answered at all! (And just because I read your answer doesn't mean I have to agree with it. Your implication above seems to be that, had I read it, I'd agree with you. Which is also offensive.) But let's keep this discussion to the _meta_ question about it.

Comment: BTW, assuming no sensitive data elsewhere in the table (which would be ridiculous), this question becomes completely safe if you just include instructions on ensuring that the MySQL user may only `SELECT`. Simples!

Answer (score 12):

There is no reason you should be building an SQL query client-side. If you're building a system that might be an exception to this rule, you wouldn't be asking this question here.

Send basic information in the AJAX request, and use that info to build a query.

Use PDO and parameterised queries to protect yourself from SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

This question can be generalised so that it can be beneficial to others coming here later. Essentially, what you're asking is "do I need to encode/decode query parameters between an ajax request and the php receiving that request?"

If we remove the discussion about what KIND of data is being sent (such as a sql query), the answer by J0HN is correct. I'd suggest altering the title of the question something similar to what I mentioned above.

To answer the more general question, the query will be urlencoded automatically as it is sent via ajax, whether that is POST or GET. PHP will make available the values in the special `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables as urldecoded values. That means you do not need to worry about urlencoding or urldecoding. The browser will encode for you, and PHP will decode for you.

Comment: Changed the title. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Could you clarify for me this? `the query will be urlencoded automatically as it is sent via ajax` is that via ajax in general or jQuery ajax?

Comment: That is in general. The browser will take care of urlencoding post and get parameters whether it is regular http or done via ajax.

Comment: @Radek interesting! Haven't discovered that.

Answer (score 1):

**Just don't do this.**

The approach takes away any and all security; no matter how secure your "internal network" is. For example, Bob could go over to Alice's desk while she's at lunch and enter `tools.php?database=db2&sql=update employee set resigned=1 where employee=alice`, or other nefarious deeds that aren't intended by your web application but made possible by insecure code.

Don't let web app users have unfettered access to what queries run in your database.

What you *should* do is work out what all your queries are going to be, and give them names.

Put these names and queries in your PHP code, and use the name alone in your web code. This puts *you* in control of what happens to the database, instead of **everyone on your network**.

Example based on the other answer:

Receiving:

```
<?php
    // presuming a PDO connection here
    $dbh = get_db_connection($_REQUEST['db']);

    // map from arbitrary name to the actual query
    // instead of giving the client control of the actual query
    switch ($_REQUEST['query']) {
    case "get-user":
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
        break;
    case "sign-in":
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET signed_in = 1 WHERE id = ?";
        break;
    default:
        die();
    }

    $sth = $db->prepare($sql);

    // assuming an array of parameters
    $params = $_REQUEST['params'];
    if (!is_array($params)) $params = array();

    // PDO makes it easy to bind positional parameters
    $sth->execute($params);

    echo json_encode($sth->fetchAll());
?>
```

Sending:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: *your backend url here*,
    data: {database: 'db', query: "get-user", "params[0]": 123},
    success: function(data, textStatus){
        //perform any processing with data returned from backend here
    }
 });
```